# Python-Extract values after specific characters and store it in columns

Tags: python

file output.txt

```
    First name: Petar

    Last Name: Petrovic

    Age: 32

    Country: USA        
    This is some description

    First name: Nick

    Last Name: Cave

    Age: 22

    Country: Brasil      
   This is another description
```

How, using a python script can I get the following output:

```
 Petar Petrovic 32 USA
 Nick Cave 22 Brasil
```

So far, i have this

```
#!/bin/python
import sys
import os
import re   
with open ("output.txt", "r") as myfile:
data=myfile.read()
```

I read that I could potentially use a dictionary but don't know how to implement that.

Comment: Are the spacings always consistent?

Comment: @chrisz, yes, it is except between country and description-just edited it in question

Comment: because i'm new to regex and not a developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re

people = re.findall(r'\bFirst name: (\S+)\s+Last Name: (\S+)\s+Age: (\d+)\s+Country: (\S+)', data)
for personinfo in people:
    print(' '.join(personinfo))
```

Output:

```
Petar Petrovic 32 USA
Nick Cave 22 Brasil
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aran-Fey definitely has a simpler answer, but another option since I've already written it:

```
with open ("output.txt", "r") as myfile:
    output = []
    for line in myfile:
        if ":" in line:
            output.append(line.split(":")[1].strip())

to_print = []
for index, elem in enumerate(output):
    if ((index+1)%5 == 0):
        print(" ".join(to_print))
        to_print = []
    to_print.append(elem)

print(" ".join(to_print))
```